# How do I get rid of the border under the table

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have setup a table and it work well for both IE and firefox.
However, when in chrome, it has a dark bottom border underlining the header.
Is there anyway to get rid of it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUrBj.png)
As compared to the image below, there is no thick black border underlining the header of the table for both IE and firefox.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu6mU.png)

```
.thresh_table
{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -46.5vh;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);

}

.thresh_box{
    height: 4vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
    font-size: 3vh;
    line-height: 3vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? Please only add tags that are relevant to the question/issue.

Comment: Please don't just report closed questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382910/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-border-under-the-table-header-in-chrome now deleted).

Comment: this is tagged with php as my entire code was written in a php script

Comment: @VincentChin but this particular code snippet has nothing to do with php

Comment: noted on that php mistake,sorry

Comment: Kindly post your Code fiddle

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre] in situations like this, always. We can not tell what a couple lines of CSS do _on their own_, without also seeing the HTML code it is supposed to apply to.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vckj1218/0jps8qy9/2/#&togetherjs=Mt8JggUAEv

Comment: thanks all who try to help me, but i have figure it out, i just got to add one line on line 364 to declare border-bottom:none